# How do I authorize a user to only see his own data with a Laravel oauth2 API?

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-5

I have created a Laravel (5.2) API with the oauth2 plugin from [lucadegasperi](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel). I use the PasswordGrant as grant type. Everything works fine, except that User A can also see the Data from User B.
How can I make sure that the users can only get their own data.

e.g. a user with the id 123 can only get data with this url: sumtotal/123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Middleware and checked the IDs.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $request_id=$request->route('cid');
    $user_id = Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId();

    if($request_id==$user_id){
        return $next($request);
    }
    abort(403, 'Access denied');
}
```